# Pandas Python Advance Filtering Through Fields to Create Sets

Tags: python, pandas, loops, filter, set

I have a dataframe where I want to identify number of sets I create. Below are the conditions it needs to meet.

1. A set must have the same brand, same color, same gender, and size.
2. It must be compose of as many Pants and Tops

## DATA

```
Brand   Type    Color   Gender  Style   Color Code  Size    Raw Data
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    1       BLK         2XL      327    
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    2       BLK         2XL       77     
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    3       BLK         2XL       25    
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    4       BLK         2XL      193        
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    5       BLK         2XL      113         
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    6       BLK         2XL       65        
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    7       BLK         2XL       93      
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    8       BLK         2XL       67        
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    9       BLK         2XL       47        
Brand 1 TOP     BLACK   WOMEN   10       BLK         2XL        0       
Brand 1 TOP     BLACK   WOMEN   11       BLK         2XL       35

Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    6       BLU         2XL       5         
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    7       BLU         2XL       5       
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    8       BLU         2XL       7         
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    9       BLU         2XL       0         
Brand 1 TOP     BLUE    WOMEN   10       BLU         2XL       0        
Brand 1 TOP     BLUE    WOMEN   11       BLU         2XL      200
```

The sets column is an example of how many sets can be created. Since, there is only 35 tops and other 35 pants can be selected from any of the pants given the condition.

An approach I wanted to do is:

filter by each brand,
 then filter by color,
 filter by gender,
 then filter by size.

Sum pants and tops and find the min.

## Manual Computation

Maximum amounts of PANTs and TOPs that can be made, by doing a sum across all sizes.

```
Brand   Type    Color   Gender       Color Code     Size    Sets
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN            BLK         2XL      1007         
Brand 1 TOP     BLACK   WOMEN            BLK         2XL       35

Max amount of sets would be 35, not enough tops.

       
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN            BLU         2XL       17        
Brand 1 TOP     BLUE    WOMEN            BLU         2XL      200

Max amount of sets would be 17, not enough pants.
```

However, I am unable to create a loop that will filter by each field and then sum. Doing this on eby one will take some time.
Can this be done or is there another way?

## Output

I will go back to original data and sum Pants and Tops to match the manual computation.

```
Brand   Type    Color   Gender  Style   Color Code  Size    Sets    Remaining
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    1       BLK         2XL     35         292
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    2       BLK         2XL      0          77
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    3       BLK         2XL      0          25
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    4       BLK         2XL      0         193
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    5       BLK         2XL      0         113
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    6       BLK         2XL      0          65
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    7       BLK         2XL      0          93
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    8       BLK         2XL      0          67
Brand 1 PANT    BLACK   WOMEN    9       BLK         2XL      0          47
Brand 1 TOP     BLACK   WOMEN   10       BLK         2XL      0           0
Brand 1 TOP     BLACK   WOMEN   11       BLK         2XL     35           0

Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    6       BLU         2XL       5          0 
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    7       BLU         2XL       5          0    
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    8       BLU         2XL       7          0      
Brand 1 PANT    BLUE    WOMEN    9       BLU         2XL       0          0      
Brand 1 TOP     BLUE    WOMEN   10       BLU         2XL       0          0     
Brand 1 TOP     BLUE    WOMEN   11       BLU         2XL      17        183
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to read through the question.

Comment: what is your expected output? Please include a dataframe of that just like you have done for input.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question to better depict the expected result.

Comment: it appears you have provided a subset of data that contains summary information of a larger dataset. In other words, it doesn't aper that we can get your answer in a reproducible manner. For example, with the provided data, how do I get to the answer of 35 for sets?

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity. I have added another color a procedure I am thinking of taking to find how many sets I need. Basically, I am summing across items as long as they have the same brand, color, gender, and type.

Comment: Thanks @ecode is my answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to groupby the columns and sum together. Then, sum the two relevant columns together again to get your answer.

```
df = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Type', 'Gender', 'Color Code', 'Size'])['Sets','Remaining'].sum().reset_index()
df['Sum amount'] = df['Sets'] + df['Remaining']
df = df.drop(['Sets','Remaining'], axis=1)
# added in the below line of code on 23-June 2020 per comment
df = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Gender', 'Color Code', 'Size'])['Sum amount'].min().reset_index() 
df
```

new output (23-July-2020):

```
    Brand   Gender  Color Code  Size    Sum amount
0   Brand 1 WOMEN   BLK         2XL     35
1   Brand 1 WOMEN   BLU         2XL     17
```

old output (16-July-2020):

```
    Brand   Type    Gender  Color Code  Size    Sum amount
0   Brand 1 PANT    WOMEN   BLK        2XL      1007
1   Brand 1 PANT    WOMEN   BLU        2XL      17
2   Brand 1 TOP     WOMEN   BLK        2XL      35
3   Brand 1 TOP     WOMEN   BLU        2XL      200
```

Comment: Thank you for the code this has given me ideas of how to approach it, but i am looking for the min value between the pant and top with the same brand, gender, color, and size. For example, I would compare line 0 and 2 from your example and use 35 for both lines.

Comment: @ecode thanks for clarifying. I have added one line of code, which I think now gives you the answer? Please mark the checkmark to accept as solution if this has helped you get the answer. Thank you!